# Does GetProcessHeap() return the same handle value within the same process if called multiple times?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-management, heap-memory

Can I assume that a handle returned by [GetProcessHeap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx) will not change within my process, or in other words, can I cache it in a global `HANDLE` variable?

Comment: Yes, the process heap is constant for the process.

Comment: It's the same every time, and it doesn't make much sense to cache it.